# Does a set polynomials (of all orders) of a complex variable form a linear vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors

Indeed all such polynomials would satisfy the commutative and associative property of addition (or so I think). However, one of the properties of vectors is that there must exist a unique null vector. But if vectors were indeed polynomials of say nth order, there should be n solutions to every polynomial when the vector becomes zero. So can we say it doesn't form an LVS because the null vector is remotely not unique?

Comment: Why did you just delete your question after I spent 20 minutes writing an answer?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I had no idea you were writing an answer. I felt bad that maybe I should do it myself, do you have it? You can post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Jorge I feel really bad I put you through so much trouble. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it. But please try not to delete questions 45 minutes after posting them. It is somewhat likely someone will be writing an answer. Especially for a problem that requires some computations.

Comment: Do you plan on posting the answer here? It would be helpful for sure

Comment: Sure I'll write it again.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: It would be better if you just undeleted it ( by going to the bottom of questions in your profile, and clicking recently deleted questions)

Comment: Oh alright. Hold on one sec

Comment: The question is back up

Comment: Great thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

The zero vector is defined as the one that when added to any vector in the space does not change it.  In the vector space of polynomials, we do not care about roots.  The null vector is the zero vector, because that is the only one you can add to, say, $x$ and still get $x$.  You can verify all the axioms of a vector space and conclude that this is one.

Although we talk of polynomials, it may be better to view them as tuples of numbers.  The powers of $x$ are just there to keep track of the order of the numbers.  You are not supposed to find roots, take derivatives, factor, or any of the things we usually do with polynomials.  You can just add the tuples or multiply them by a scalar.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! What's the dimensionality of the space?

Answer (score 2):

The polynomials of *exactly* degree $n$ do not form a vector space. Apart from the problem with the zero polynomial not being of degree $n$, we also have that the sum of two polynomials of equal degree may be a polynomial of lower degree. For example,
\begin{align}
p(x) &= 2x^2-3x+5 && \text{(degree 2)}\\
q(x) &= -2x^2+5x+3 && \text{(degree 2)}\\
\implies p(x)+q(x) &= 2x+8 && \text{(degree 1)}
\end{align}
However the polynomials of degree *at most* $n$ do form a vector space, of dimension $n+1$. Note that the zero polynomial typically gets assigned the formal degree $-\infty$, so it is included.

Also the set of all polynomials forms a vector space. This vector space has infinite dimension, as you need infinitely many basis vectors (for example, the polynomials of the form $x^k,k\in\mathbb N$ form a basis; omit just one of them, and there will be polynomials you no longer can form).

Comment: Why is the dimension of such a vector space n+1?

Comment: @RichardKiddman: Because you need $n+1$ basis vectors. For example, take $n=2$, that is, polynomials of the form $ax^2+bx+c$. You immediately see that there are three parameters ($a,b,c$), and they are indeed factors to a basis (namely the basis $x^2,x,1$). You can see that they form a basis because they are linearly independent (the only way that $ax^2+bx+c$ is the zero polynomial is if all three of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are zero) and span the whole space (that is, every polynomial of degree at most two can be written as $ax^2+bx+c$ with appropriate values of $a$, $b$ and $c$).

Comment: Ah yes, there is the last constant term which perplexed me. Thank you so much!